# Extra space after \newenvironment

Tags: environments

I have a file with the following environment

```
\newenvironment{system}{\begin{equation} \left \{ \begin{aligned} }{\end{aligned} \right . \end{equation}}
```

Which produced the result that I'm looking for except from the fact that adds a little extra space on the new line after the environment so for instance, if I write

```
\begin{system}
x + y &= 1\\
x - y &= 2
\end{system}
foo
```

foo gets printed one space after the next line.
On the other hand, if I have

```
\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{aligned}
x + y &= 1\\
x - y &= -1
\end{aligned}
\rigth .
\end{equation}
foo
```

Then foo gets printed where it should. On the other hand if I write `foo` right after `\end{system}` with no spaces or newline I get the correct result but then the text file gets a little harder to read.

Am I doing something wrong in defining the environment? Or is there an easy way to solve it.

Edit: For context, this is the preamble I am testing it in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\newenvironment{system}
  {\begin{equation} \left \{ \begin{aligned} }
  {\end{aligned} \right . \end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!